# Phase diagram for oxygen

Tags: phase-transition

Do you know where can I find simple diagram (solid, liquid, gas) for for oxygen?

EDIT: I made a mistake. I wanted oxygen instead of water. sorry.

Answer (score 2):

For **water**, see e.g.

> http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~gladish/teaching/eao/week2.html

But if you also wanted to see some exotic high-pressure phases of ice, see

> http://www.btinternet.com/~martin.chaplin/phase.html

For **oxygen** in the updated question, see

> http://images.google.cz/images?q=phase+diagram+oxygen&biw=1031&bih=783

e.g.

> http://www.azonano.com/Details.asp?ArticleID=1797

Comment: But there are very difficult ones. Also there is lots of other diagrams like CO2 water etc. I need just one easy showing liquid, solid and gas phases of oxygen. It's not as easy to google as you think. Exactly I need temperatures around 273 +- 50K

Comment: @oneat: The "easy" part is contained in the full picture.